# Strange issue in this query. It is not inserting a particular value

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I have an insert process. My development is under **Drupal6**. So i used the following method to insert into database table.

```
$sid = $user->sid;
$data   = array(
            'nid'           =>  $parent_nid,
            'vid'           =>  $parent_vid,
            'uid'           =>  $user_id,
            'time_start'    =>  time(),
            'session_id'    =>  $sid
);

drupal_write_record('quiz_node_results', $data);
```

Here the problem is, it is not inserting the value `$sid`. It inserts the default value 0 always in that field. But other values are inserted correctly. But it has value. I checked with by putting `print_r($data)`.

In database table, `session_id` field's datatype is `varchar`.

For quick fix, i wrote actual insert query and inserted into it. That query is below.

```
$sql    =   "INSERT INTO {quiz_node_results}(nid, vid, uid, time_start, session_id) VALUES(".$parent_nid.",".$parent_vid.",".$user_id.",".time().", '".$sid."')";
db_query($sql);
```

It is working fine and inserts the value correctly. But i don't want to insert in this way because it is vulnerable.

I want to know why the above one is not working. Can anyone suggest where i went wrong?

Comment: We will have to see this method `drupal_write_record` to be able to tell

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ That is drupal's library method to insert a record.

Comment: Did you try `var_dump($data)` to see if `$data` is correct?

Comment: @piotrekkr var_dump gives ["session_id"]=> string(26) "t3kdqnn7t5ie8ls9i2abapcus6" for that variable.

Comment: Is `session_id` a primary key? If so then it seems that it is ommited on update. Read comments inside this function: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/7

Comment: @piotrekkr no.. session_id is not a primary key

Comment: Does drupal use cached table schemas somwhere or is he always reading fresh table schema before insert?

Comment: @piotrekkr There is no cache at all. Everytime it reads fresh table schema only

Comment: Try debug it by temporary changing `drupal_write_record` like this: `if ($table == 'quiz_node_results') var_dump($query, $fields, $object);` before return statement. It should show you what is going inside function.

Comment: Are you using `global $user` to retrieve the user's info? Or something else like `user_load($user_id)`?

Comment: @jerdiggity i am using this to get user's info. I am getting values correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure changing line 1 from this:

```
$sid = $user->sid;
```

to this:

```
$sid = isset($user->sid) ? $user->sid : session_id();
```

should do the trick...